# How to animate the whole screen when colision?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I want to make the screen shake when an enemy colide with the player. I have been searching for a posible answer but I don find anything. If someone can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
func shakeFrame(scene: SKScene) {

    let animation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    animation.duration = 0.05
    animation.repeatCount = 4
    animation.autoreverses = true
    animation.fromValue = NSValue(CGPoint: CGPointMake(scene.view!.center.x - 4.0, scene.view!.center.y))
    animation.toValue = NSValue(CGPoint: CGPointMake(scene.view!.center.x + 4.0, scene.view!.center.y))
    scene.view!.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "position")
}
```

in your case try this

```
func shakeFrame(scene: SKScene) {

    let animation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    animation.duration = 0.05
    animation.repeatCount = 4
    animation.autoreverses = true
    animation.fromValue = NSValue(CGPoint: CGPointMake(scene.view!.center.x - 4.0, scene.view!.center.y))
    animation.toValue = NSValue(CGPoint: CGPointMake(scene.view!.center.x + 4.0, scene.view!.center.y))
    scene.view!.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "position")
}

if hits < 2 && circuloPrincipal.color != enemigo.color {
    shakeFrame()
}
```

Comment: I have added it to my colision func but it doesnt make the animation

Comment: Diego I have to seriously question your skill level, and might recommend that you start with some swift basic tutorials. This is a function. You call a function not insert it into a code block.

Comment: if it works, and answers your question please mark it as the correct answer